# Python for loops: applying a value to one index and another one to the other indexes

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to create a program that will allow a game reviewer to input what categories the game falls under, it should then print the appropriate category with a checkbox, and the other categories with a blank box.

I have managed to write a for loop that prints out the correct category with the checkbox, but am struggling to loop through the rest of the values to print them with a blank box.

```
yes = '\u2611' #checkbox
no = '\u2610' #blank box

audience_list = ["Kids", "Everyone", "Casual Players", "Pro Players"]
audience= int(input("1. Kids, 2. Everyone, 3. Casual 4. Pro: "))

print ("===[ Audience: ]===")

for i in audience_list: #cycles through the list of audience options
    if i == audience_list[audience-1]: #for the audience option that was selected, print it with a check box
        print ("%s %s" % (yes, audience_list[audience-1]))
    else: #for the audience options weren't selected, print them with a blank checkbox
        print ("%s %s" % (no, audience_list))
```

Is there a way for me to print every index other than the one that has been assigned to the 'audience' variable?

I'm using Python 3.2.3.

Comment: what `name` variable?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the audience variable - will edit my question

Comment: No problem, does my answer give the output you were looking for?

Comment: It does! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print `i`! If you print `audience_list`, you will output the whole list of every element; whereas `i` is the one you are currently checking.

```
for i in audience_list:
    if i == audience_list[audience-1]:
        print ("%s %s" % (yes, audience_list[audience-1]))
    else:
        print ("%s %s" % (no, i))
```

and a test (having entered `3`) gives a neat output of:

```
☐ Kids
☐ Everyone
☑ Casual Players
☐ Pro Players
```

Comment: Note that in this case, the yes line could just be `print ( "%s %s" % (yes, i))`.  Incidentally, this gives you an opportunity to reduce the function further: `print ( "%s %s" % (yes if i == audience_list[audience-1] else no, i))`  Then you could technically map through a lambda and do everything on one line, but there's not really much gained by going that far.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Most pieces of code can be written on one line, but according to [the zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), simple is better than complex. However, yes in my own code, I would do as you say :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider [enumerating](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) the list items:

```
audience_list = ["Kids", "Everyone", "Casual Players", "Pro Players"]
choice = 3  # Casual.

for (index, name) in enumerate(audience_list, start=1):
    if index == choice:
        print("[X] " + name)
    else:
        print("[ ] " + name)
```

Output:

```
[ ] Kids
[ ] Everyone
[X] Casual Players
[ ] Pro Players
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this because I feel the other answers haven't answered your underlying question.

Here's the code I propose:

```
yes = '\u2611' #checkbox
no = '\u2610' #blank box

audience_list = ["Kids", "Everyone", "Casual Players", "Pro Players"]
audience= int(input("1. Kids, 2. Everyone, 3. Casual 4. Pro: "))
selection = audience_list[audience-1]

print ("===[ Audience: ]===")

for option in audience_list: #cycles through the list of audience options
    print ("%s %s" % (yes if option == selection else no, option))
```

There are two major changes here.

First, I created the variable `selection`, outside of your `for` loop.  This cleans up your loop and is closer to what you're doing.  You don't care about the number, you care about what the user selected.

Second, I put the `if` part of your for loop into the `print` statement.  This is to highlight something important: the only difference you want in each iteration of your loop is whether or not the box is checked.  Either way, you want to print the element of `audience_list`.  This print statement shows that.  You either print an empty box or a checked one, and either way, you print the element.

Note that some confusion may have come from your `for i`..., because typically an `i` like that is an int.  Consequently, I changed my for loop iterator to be named `option`, which is much more clearly a string.

I think your main question gets addressed by this.  You could have printed `audience_list[audience-1]` in both your yes and no lines, or you could more simply have printed `i` in both of your lines.  (Or, as per Joe's code at this time, you could have made one `audience_list[audience-1]` and one `i`, since as it's written, they're both the same.)  But since you're looping through all the options, other than the box, you should print the same option string, whether it's selected or not.

Note, in my comments with Joe, I mentioned that you could squeeze the for loop and below all on to one line.  Then your code would look like this:

```
yes = '\u2611' #checkbox
no = '\u2610' #blank box

audience_list = ["Kids", "Everyone", "Casual Players", "Pro Players"]
audience= int(input("1. Kids, 2. Everyone, 3. Casual 4. Pro: "))
selection = audience_list[audience-1]

print ("===[ Audience: ]===")

_ = list(map(lambda o: print ( "%s %s" % (yes if o == selection else no, o)), audience_list))
```

This is logically equivalent, but a lot harder to read, so while it's fun to do, I wouldn't recommend it.  (Briefly: `map` takes a function, in this case, the unnamed lambda function, and runs every member of the iterator audience_list through that function.  `list` is necessary to make the map object actually do the processing, and the `_ =` is just to tell any other readers that we know we're throwing away the list.)

As Joe mentions, there is a less ugly way to do it that doesn't require mapping.  The last line could be:

```
_ = [print ( "%s %s" % (yes if o == selection else no, o)) for o in audience_list]
```

This is slightly less confusing, since it removes the `list(map(` noise.

These are pretty much all functionally equivalent.  And while it's fun to toss things in to a single line, don't get lost in that.  Readability, maintainability and the ability to easily debug are the most critical.

Comment: Creds to writing such an in-depth answer. However, although I would definitely agree that the changes you made improve the readability of the code, from an algorithmic standpoint, it is identical. You are still using a `for` and `if`. As a result I am slightly unsure of your statement: "I think your main question gets solved by this". I am uncertain of what you mean by this. Finally, if I may just add, I think your last line of code is kind of an abomination. Not only is it unpythonic, but it simply doesn't work - you forgot to add the parameter to iterate over!

Comment: And if you were going to do this in one-line, I would use a `list-comp`. A) it removes the additional call to `list()` to execute it, B) it is considered generally more Pythonic and C) they are more readable than `map()`.

Comment: Thanks for catching my missing parameter.  I had a tested version, then retyped without testing.  It's fixed now.  Interestingly, I've always thought of using map for executing over a list; I'd never have thought of doing a list comprehension there.  I added it in.  It actually is much more readable than mapping a lambda - _almost_ enough to actually want to use that over the for loop.

Comment: My comment about solving the actual question - I wanted to stress to OP that in a for loop with an if statement, you don't have to "print every index other than the one that has been assigned to the audience variable" - the `for`/`if` construct does that.  The two statements within the if and else should be the same, other than printing a checked vs unchecked box.  I felt that wasn't stated clearly in yours or 9000's answers.